# Google CloudSQL 2nd gen instance stopped and stuck restarting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We are currently using a 2nd gen Google CloudSQL instance. We recently switched over from a 1st gen instance because we heard 2nd gen was faster (and we assumed more reliable).

For some reason during a nightly database sync between the client's private database and our CloudSQL database the instance just stopped. It did not reach any caps as to CPU usage, memory usage, storage capacity, etc. We noticed and restarted the instance hours later but the instance has been stuck "Restarting".

[image]

We ended up copying the instance to a backup and running the production site on the backup instance.

Does anyone have an idea as to what may cause an instance to die like it did for us?

Also does anyone have an idea as to why our instance seems to be stuck in restarting?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please send your instance name to cloud-sql@google.com, we will help you there.

Comment: @Tianzhou Thank you! I sent in an email since we still have questions. We also sent in a ticket yesterday and the support said he would talk to the engineering team to get our instance back up and running. It eventually did come back up but we didn't get an update on what happened or that it came back.